# Save email as draft in PHP and how to make runtime fields in database?

Tags: php, jquery, html, database-design

in my PHP site i want to build there are many user that will create a survey question to ask the people's my point is that if one user make 10 question and other make 20 question how will i manage this issue with MYSQL database how to store dynamic value's?

Answer (score 2):

Have two tables, `Quizzes`, and `Questions`. Have `Quizzes` contain data about the quiz other than the questions and have the `Questions` table contain a field for a `Quiz_ID` that is a foreign key to an `ID` field in `Quizzes`. The `Questions` table can have a field for the question, and it's answer. This way to add questions you just add rows, you don't need to modify tables.

Comment: ok i will manage ralationship of table but my point is that if one user make 2 question and other user make 100 question how will database handle 2 question for user1 and 100 question user2 and also tell me how i will save as draft if user wrongly press close button?

Comment: For the draft bit have ajax send the form to the server every few minutes with an added value of "draft=1" or something like that. In the Quizzes table you'll need a field for "user".